# How to execute a function every n seconds in python using aysncio

Tags: python, loops, task, python-asyncio

Basically I got a function, I want it to repeat infinitely with the interval of 30 seconds. is it possible to do this with async def function?

```
async def test():
  await print("Hello")
```

how to repeat it after every 30 seconds?

Comment: Any feedback please?

Answer (score 0):

Use `asyncio.sleep` in a while loop to do it:

```py
import asyncio


async def test():
    while True:
        print("Hello")
        await asyncio.sleep(30)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(test())
```